# Meteor MUP - Mongo version 4 incompatible

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mup

I was very happy to learn that the new Meteor versions support Mongo v4.
It seems that MUP does not...

If I run 'mup setup' with these mongo settings in mup.js everything goes fine.

```
 module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '****',

    }
  },

meteor: {
name: 'nascholingen',
path: '/webserver/nascholingen',
        volumes:{
        '/webserver/nascholingen/private/.uploads':'/webserver/nascholingen/private/.uploads',
        '/webserver/nascholingen/private/.downloads':'/webserver/nascholingen/private/.downloads',
        '/webserver/nascholingen/backups/nascholingen':'/webserver/nascholingen/backups/nascholingen'
},

servers: {
  one: {
        env:{
                PDFMERGE_PATH: "/usr/bin/pdfmerge",
        }
},
},

buildOptions: {
  serverOnly: true,
},

env: {

  ROOT_URL: '*****',
  MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor',
        PORT:'3002'
},

docker: {
  image: 'appworkshop/meteord-graphicsmagick-pdftk-node8:node-8.9.1-base',
},

deployCheckWaitTime: 60,


enableUploadProgressBar: false
},
 mongo: {
        port: 27017,
       version: "3.6.16",
        servers: {
          one: {}
        }
  }
};
```

When I change 'version' to 4.0.6 or anything higher, mup setup shows:

```
 Connection refused :
        connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
        @(connect):2:6
        2019-12-21T18:07:28.576+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
        2019-12-21T18:07:28.576+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
        MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
        connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
        2019-12-21T18:07:33.737+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: ca
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the complete (anonymized) mup config. Maybe you use an incompatible meteor docker image?

Comment: As a workaround you can install mongodb on the same instance or separate one and connect to that instead.
Also you need to update node version in your docker image